# How can I reduce over-allocation of cluster resources due to multiple Jenkins instances?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift

If a large organization needs to provide Jenkins to several teams, each team or application `namespace` will run its own instance of Jenkins. This allocates a lot of compute resources when the number of instances grow into the hundreds and are often underutilized.

What is the best solutions to tackle this problem? I have some ideas that I haven't fully researched yet:

1. Reduce the default CPU/memory `requests`/`limits` in the OpenShift Jenkins template (in Catalogue). **Concern**: These may be overwritten on deploy.
2. Use a central, shared Jenkins instance. **Concern**: May not have enough isolation or control via RBAC to isolate teams to their own projects/pipelines.
3. Sharing Jenkins agents, keep deploying separate masters for teams/applications. **Concern**: Not sure if this is possible or drastically increases complexity.
4. Leverage vertical pod autoscaling (VPA) to adjust Jenkins pods requests dynamically. **Concern**: Not sure if this would improve the issue.
5. Simply reduce overall projects ResourceQuotas, specially lowering the requests and relying more on limits. **Concern**: Increased risk of `OOM` situations.

Comment: Have you looked into HPA

Comment: I don't think HPA would help here. I'm looking for a way to reduce the overcommitment of underutilized (multiple) Jenkins instances across the cluster.

Comment: I've been curious about how [Node sharing executor](https://plugins.jenkins.io/node-sharing-executor/) might work ... "Share machines as Jenkins agents across multiple Jenkins masters."

Comment: Do you consider that point 2. is more complex than managing "hundreds and often underutilized" instance of Jenkins? IMHO point 2. is the way to go...Just curious if you have hundreds of jenkins instances running, how many "thousand of jobs" are defined in those instances? It sounds like a major flaw in your  architecture here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with approach **5** as it is the least disruptive.

Full details can be found [here](https://github.com/BCDevOps/developer-experience/blob/master/docs/resource-tuning-recommendations.md).